# Not able to debug node js app from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I want to debug my node application(via webstorm10 & i've also 9),i've put breakpoint in the required 
file and edit the run configuration like following (for local debug I want to debug local host...) ,I want to send some post message via postman or fiddler and simply debug it...
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

the issue is that my program is using the following code

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

and when you click on debug(in WS) you get every time **new port** like

```
Debugger listening on port 59267
```

what I should do in this case?

I wanted to debug the `app.get('/aa', function(req, res) {`

when I put in the browser `http://localhost:59267/aa`
its not stops and I got in the browser the following response:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 3.28.73
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v0.12.2
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: why are you using debug port in URL instead of actual port your application listens on (3000 or process.env.PORT)?

Answer (score 0):

always use process.env.PORT or 3000 in the browser

you can get the actual port like below:

```
console.log('Server running at port:' + app.get('port'));
```